# Multithreading in PHP 7

Tags: php, pthreads, php-7

How to do multithreading in PHP7? The first problem I see with `pthread` is coming directly from PHP manual.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php

> *The **pthreads** extension **cannot** be used in a **web server environment**. Threading in PHP should therefore remain to **CLI-based** applications only.*

Is is safe to oversee this warning, and spawn some threads on HTTP requests?

Comment: did you tried doing that .. Or use some other things like Rabbit MQ, Gearman etc.

Comment: I read some about Gearman. My understanding is that it will be a standalone process to interface with. Did not check any MQs yet. But I am talking about the language itself.

Comment: Gearman  is good i use it .. you can use supervisord to monitor all your process. It basically works in back with as many threads you create

Answer (score 3):

> Is is safe to oversee this warning, and spawn some threads on HTTP requests?

The extension itself prohibits loading anywhere but CLI: Attempting to load in any other SAPI will result in a fatal error.

Comment: The library prohibits that. Yet there are workarounds http://www.smddzcy.com/2016/01/tutorial-multi-threading-in-php7-pthreads/

Comment: That's not a workaround, it's instructions for how to load pthreads in CLI only.

Comment: So what is the answer for the main question? How to do multithreading php7?

Comment: @AmrElAdawy I think php doesn't support multi-threading when it comes to HTTP request. this conclude that you need another programming language. From my opinion the best language for this is GO.