# Multithreading in PHP?

Tags: php, multithreading

I am coming from java background which has rich threading framework. In the past , I kept hearing that PHP does not support threading.
But below code from this [site](http://php.net/manual/en/thread.start.php) creates the thread in PHP in almost same way as java does.
So what's  the difference ?

```
<?php

class ChildThread extends Thread {
    public $data;

    public function run() {
      /* Do some work */

      $this->data = 'result';
    }
}

$thread = new ChildThread();
```

Also I read below statements on google

> Avoid the idea of running paralell tasks (threads or processes) in
>   PHP. It has some modules for this purpose, but they are not available
>   on every platform and are not part of the PHP core, so the chances for
>   you to be able to use them are very low.
>
> This way wil not  will work in every single environment

So My question above way of creating thread thread does not work on every platform(which platform for example) ? Does it mean there is no true
way of creating thread that works on all environment ?

Comment: If your question is about PHP, please do not tag it with Java.  There is no benefit to you attracting Java experts to this question.

Comment: [From the author of `pthreads`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209774/does-php-have-threading/14548828#14548828)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multithreading in PHP 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266813/multithreading-in-php-7)

Comment: PHP don't work with threads in a native way, it's necessary extensions to enable this kind of feature and only will work properly on CLI-based applications.

For parallelism you can work with pcntl functions or pthread, but as i said, it maybe not practicable on web apps.